# DbTransaction class and about interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I came across an example of the implementation an an interface. Portion of code is

```
public partial interface IDataProvider
{
    DataTable GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes();

    void AlterEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes(DataTable lookUpTable);
}

public partial class DataProvider : IDataProvider
{    

    public DataTable GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes()
    {
        return GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes((DbTransaction)null);
    }
    public DataTable GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes(DbTransaction tran)
    {
        //Db Operations
    }
}
```

My first question is about this "DbTransaction" class. Its not in my project, is it a build in class?

My second question is, why in the DataProvider (the implementing class), the function is calling another overload of itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DbTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbtransaction.aspx) is a common base-class for representing database transactions in ADO.NET; each actual ADO.NET provider subclasses this (typically) - for example `SqlTransaction : DbTransaction` (the sql-server client).

Calling an overload of self is a common way of implementing optional parameters, **without code duplication** prior to their addition in C# 4.0. In this case, that is essentially a pre-4.0 way of implementing:

```
public DataTable GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes(DbTransaction tran = null) {...}
```

either implementation (overloads or optional parameter) allows usage of the form:

```
obj.GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes(); // without transaction
obj.GetEmployeeAbsenceDurationTypes(tran); // with transaction
```

Comment: so what do you prefer. I call from method its overload or just call it simply? because first method is not doing anything else than returning the value from its own overload.

Comment: @Cancer that depends: is your library intended for C# 4.0 clients? (and VB clients, who have had support for this for ages) - if so, optional parameters are nice and compact. If you need to support clients that *don't* have access to optional parameters, you could use overloads, or you could just document "pass null for no transaction"

Answer (score 4):

The first question is impossible to answer *for sure* without seeing the whole code, but it's probably referring to [`System.Data.Common.DbTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbtransaction.aspx).

As for the implementation - presumably it's a way of reusing the code, that's all. If the implementation of the method *with* a parameter can handle a parameter value of `null` as "do it in a new transaction" (or whatever the behaviour of the parameterless method should be) naturally, why *wouldn't* you want one overload to call the other?